# Cannot change button background using themes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I want to set custom styles for a Button in my app, but I try to do it setting a custom theme and it's not working. For example this doesn't change the background

```
<Button
  android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
  ... />

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

If I do the same thing using styles it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening there is that the background attribute is getting overridden by the default style of the `Button`. The default style is set in your Theme, if you take a look at `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` (the theme you're inheriting from) you'll see the following inheritance structure:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
    Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
        Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light
            Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light
```

In `Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light` you'll find the `buttonStyle` attribute definition, which is the default style for the `Button` element:

```
<item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button</item>
```

Again, if you take a look at `Widget.AppCompat.Button` you'll find that it inherits from `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button` and that it sets the `android:background` attribute (between other ones).

So, in order to change the style of the `Button` in a theme, you should use the `buttonStyle` property. Your safest bet would be create a new style the inherits from `Widget.AppCompat.Button` (so you do not lose all other attributes that are being set there) and set the android:background attribute there:

```
<style name="CustomStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="buttonStyle">@style/CustomStyle</item>
</style>
```